# qmenu does not work on MAC (Qt Creator)

Tags: c++, qt, osx-snow-leopard

i'm on Mac 10.6, i'm trying to create a menu with Qt (Creator), but the menu does not appear. I had some feed back from other pc users, and the same code seems to work on windows :

```
#include <QtGui>  
#include "MyClass.h"  

MyClass::MyClass()  
{  
// Create a menu
    //QMainWindow::setMenuBar(new QMenuBar());  
    QMenu* my_menu = new QMenu("&File", this);  
    menuBar()->addMenu(my_menu);  
}
```

Have you heard about this kind of problem with mac?

The toolbar works fine, but the menu doesn't.

EDIT : 
new code :

```
#include <QtGui>
#include "MMenu.h"

MMenu::MMenu()
{
    QMenu* fileMenu = new QMenu("&File", this);
    QMenuBar *menuBar = new QMenuBar(0);
    menuBar->addMenu(fileMenu);
    //menuBar()->addMenu(fileMenu);
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Macs have only the one menu bar. Let me dig through some of my code... I know you can use it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you may be interested in the addMenu(QString) function, which returns the created QMenu in one step.

Second, try adding something to the menu. Macs may be optimizing the empty menu away. But I know this should work, I've written a program that did just fine on OSX that initialized the menus in this way.

Comment: Thanks Robert, i found something about "Mac" windows in the doc, saying we should use "QMenu" without a parent, but it still makes no difference. i updated my post above with the new code, but unfortunately the menu bar still doesn't appear

Comment: hi Robert, okay it actually appears on "top" of my window, not inside my Qt window, but at the top left corner of the mac!

Comment: Yes, that's how the OSX menus work. There's one per application, and it's on the main menu bar at the top of the screen. I'm not sure I even know of any "native" OSX applications that have a window-owned menu... they're all X11 apps or something and stick out like a sore thumb

Answer (score 0):

```
QMenu *fileMenu = QMainWindow::menuBar()->addMenu(tr("&File"));
fileMenu->addAction(your_action);
fileMenu->addAction(your_second_action); 
...
```

in the constructor or wherever you want it. And if you just wanna have a look at it before your main windows runs, just do

```
fileMenu->exec();
```